# thread should have started running after i created an object with start() in constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

There are 2 classes i used

1st class: Counter

```
public class Counter {
int val = 0;
void inc() { val++;}
void dcr() { val--;}
}
```

2nd class: threadTesting

```
public class ThreadTesting extends Thread {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
Counter c;
ThreadTesting(Counter c){
    this.c = c;
    start();
}

public void run(){
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        c.dcr();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Counter c = new Counter();
    ThreadTesting rc = new ThreadTesting(c);
    Boolean stateOfThread = rc.isAlive();
    System.out.println(stateOfThread);
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
       c.inc();
    rc.join();

    System.out.println("Final value of c.val: "+c.val);
}

}
```

if I commented these code

```
 Boolean stateOfThread = rc.isAlive();
    System.out.println(stateOfThread);
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
       c.inc();
    rc.join();
```

The result i get would be 0, but the child thread should be started once i created the object rc but it didn't. Why ?

Comment: Note: starting a thread in a constructor is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: The problem isn't that the thread isn't started, it's that updates to the variable aren't visible to the other threads. Make `val` `volatile` (or just use an `AtomicInteger` instead).

Comment: @AndyTurner Much more likely that it prints before the thread had a chance to update the variable.

Comment: But even then the value might be 0 since you omit the `join`.

Comment: Next time, please just post the code you're asking about, not extraneous code. If you're asking why you get 0 when you've commented out a big block of the code you've shown, just don't show that code at all.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Bizarrely, the OP isn't even asking about that part. Also bizarrely, I get a non-0 result (which varies run to run) when I add `volatile` (also when I don't, but that I understand). I have to admit I don't understand why (but then, my Java multi-threading is very rusty).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What you mean with the full code? Nothing bizarre it's the expected behavior (++ is not atomic) volatile doesn't change anything visibility is guaranteed with volatile, doesn't mean there is none without.

Comment: @Oleg: Ah, `++` isn't atomic. Thanks. I used to know that, when I worked in Java regularly. :-) Does indeed explain it. What I mean with my other comment is that what the OP's asking about is why he/she sees what he/she sess **without** five lines of that code. So quoting the code, complete with the five lines that shouldn't be there, is just confusing and distracting.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment the mentioned statements, the constructor would still start the second thread, but `System.out.println("Final value of c.val: "+c.val);` is executed on the main thread before the second thread's `run()` method starts. Therefore `c.val` is still `0` when the output is printed.

Add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` prior to that print statement and you'll see the second thread does run.

You'll most likely get an output of:

```
Final value of c.val: -10000
```

Comment: `-10000` is not guaranteed, in theory he can get any output because of visibility and scheduling.

Comment: @Oleg In that simple program it is extremely likely the second thread execution will finish by the time the main thread resumes execution after the sleep period is done.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nothing in the jls guarantees that `System.out.println("Final value of c.val: "+c.val);` will see updates to `c.val` from another thread even if it finished executing. A happens-before relationship needs to be established and it wasn't in this case.

Comment: @Oleg: I'll trust you on the theory. I have trouble believing in practice that the quoted code with Eran's one-second sleep would ever fail to show -10000. But I'm sure you're right and it would be dangerous to take an isolated case and then generalize it to a situation where the theory may well rear up and bite you. :-)